# transparent component with aviwriter in aforge

Tags: c#, aforge

I want to  make an avi video with aforge and I am trying to add bitmap frame with ARGB the A component (transparent component) is not working please is there any way to add transparent to aviwriter frame with aforge.net c# (even if not bitmap)

```
 Bitmap my_video_image = new Bitmap(picturebox1.Image);
                for (int i = 0; i < heigth11; i++)
                     {
                for (int j = 0; j < width11; j++)
                  {
                         my_video_image.SetPixel(j,i,Color.FromArgb(trackBar4.Value,red,green, blue));

                   }
                     }
                    AVIWriter avi_Writer= new AVIWriter();
                    avi_Writer.Open("videoname.avi",600,600);
                    avi_Writer.AddFrame(my_video_image);
```

the avi WRiter added the image but without the tranparent component

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried  and I Edit my question

Comment: What PixelFormat does your my_video_image have?

Comment: if you show the image in picture box the transparent component works but with the avi_writer it dose not work that what i know .

Comment: the alpha component(transparent component) will not work with aviwriter because the frames in the aviwriter do not recognize the transparent of the pixel and i hop evrey one knows that now